# Why is Minidump file contents wrong for only 1 process?

Tags: winapi, mfc

***Situation:***
We have an MFC/C++ Visual Studio (2005) application consisting of a lot of executables and a lot of dlls, all using MFC and interconnected with DCOM. Some are running on a controller (w2012) which controls slave computers running on WES2009.

***The problem:***
For diagnostic purposes we are embedding minidumps in all of our processes. This mechanism works fine in all processes except for one: the GUI exe. All processes including the GUI make dmp files **BUT** the dmp file contents of the GUI seems to be **different/wrong**. When I intentionally crash our application with e.g. a null pointer dereference, all dmp files of all processes/dlls (except GUI) point to the cause (the null pointer dereference)! The dmp file of the GUI process is created and can be openend in Visual Studio but non of the threads point to the cause (the null pointer dereference). Also windbg does not find the cause! The strange thing is that when we manually use WriteStackDetails() to dump the callstack it returns the correct problematic line! So why can't MinidumpWriteDump() do the same for only this one process? What could be the discriminating factor? Anyone any idea?

***What we tried:***
We tried crashes in all other process and dlls and they all seem to work ok except the GUI process! Unicode / non-Unicode does not seem to matter. A seperate test application works well, also when I link our production code library which contains the UnhandledExceptionFilter() and MinidumpWriteDump(). Crashes in sub(-sub) dlls does not seem to matter. The project settings wrt exception handling appear to be all the same. Anyone any idea?

Some more info and remarks:

1. Our production code (controller and slaves) is running in separate virtual boxes for development purposes.
2. yes we understand that the minidump should ideally be created from another process (some example somewhere? wrt process querying and security?) but doing it in-process seems to work 'always ok' for now. So we accept the risk for now that it might hang in rare situations.
3. What I mean with the dmp file contents is different/wrong is the following:
   For our non-GUI exe we get the following OK thread / callstack information:
   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
   Studio automatically opens the correct source and the "breakpoint" is set to the faulty line of code.
   In the Call stack tab I see my own functions in my own dll which has caused the crash: my null pointer dereference.
   In the Threads tab I also see my active thread and Location which points also to the faulty function which crashed.
   So all is fine and usable in this situation! Super handy functionality!

For our GUI exe, which links to the same production library code wrt MinidumpWriteDump() and ExceptionHandlingFiler() code, we get the following NOK thread / callstack information:
Unhandled exception at 0x77d66e29 (ntdll.dll) in our_exe_pid_2816_tid_2820_crash.dmp: 0xC0150010: The activation context being deactivated is not active for the current thread of execution
Visual Studio 2005 does not show my faulty code as being the cause!
In the Call stack tab I don't see my own faulty function.
The Call stack tab shows that the problem is in ntdll.dll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast()
The top most function call which is shown of our code is in a totally different gui helper dll, which is not related to my intentionally introduced crash!
The Threads tab also shows the same.

For both situations I use the same visual studio 2005 (running on w7) with the same settings for symbol paths!!! Also visual studio 2017 cannot analyze the 'wrong' dmp files. In between of both test above, there is no rebuild so no mismatch occurs between exe/dlls and pdbs. In one situation it works fine and in another not!?!

4. The stripped-down-to-essentials code we use is shown below

   ```
   typedef BOOL (_stdcall *tMiniDumpWriteDump)(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD dwPid, HANDLE hFile, 
                                           MINIDUMP_TYPE DumpType, CONST PMINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION ExceptionParam,
                                           CONST PMINIDUMP_USER_STREAM_INFORMATION UserStreamParam,
                                           CONST PMINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INFORMATION CallbackParam);
   ```

   TCHAR CCrashReporter::s_szLogFileNameDmp[MAX_PATH];
   CRITICAL_SECTION CCrashReporter::s_csGuard;
   LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER CCrashReporter::s_previousFilter = 0;
   HMODULE CCrashReporter::s_hDbgHelp = 0;
   tMiniDumpWriteDump    CCrashReporter::s_fpMiniDumpWriteDump = 0;

   CCrashReporter::CCrashReporter()
   {
     LoadDBGHELP();

   s_previousFilter = ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExceptionFilter);
     ::InitializeCriticalSection(&s_csGuard);
   }

   CCrashReporter::~CCrashReporter()
   {
     ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(s_previousFilter);

   ...

   if (0 != s_hDbgHelp)
     {
       FreeLibrary(s_hDbgHelp);
     }

   ::DeleteCriticalSection(&s_csGuard);
   }

   LONG WINAPI CCrashReporter::UnhandledExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo)
   {
     ::EnterCriticalSection(&s_csGuard);

   ...

   GenerateMinidump(pExceptionInfo, s_szLogFileNameDmp);
     ::LeaveCriticalSection(&s_csGuard);
     return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
   }

   void CCrashReporter::LoadDBGHELP()
   {
     /* ... search for dbghelp.dll code ... */

   s_hDbgHelp = ::LoadLibrary(strDBGHELP_FILENAME);

   if (0 == s_hDbgHelp)
     {
       /* ... report error ... */
     }

   if (0 != s_hDbgHelp)
     {
       ...

   ```
   s_fpMiniDumpWriteDump = (tMiniDumpWriteDump)GetProcAddress(s_hDbgHelp, "MiniDumpWriteDump");

   if (!s_fpMiniDumpWriteDump)
   {
     FreeLibrary(s_hDbgHelp);
   }
   else
   {
     /* ... log ok ... */
   }
   ```

   }
   }

   void CCrashReporter::GenerateMinidump(const PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo,
                                         LPCTSTR pszLogFileNameDmp)
   {
     HANDLE hReportFileDmp(::CreateFile(pszLogFileNameDmp, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0,
                                        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, 0));

   if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hReportFileDmp)
     {
       MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION stMDEI;

   ```
   stMDEI.ThreadId = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
   stMDEI.ExceptionPointers = pExceptionInfo;
   stMDEI.ClientPointers = TRUE;

   if(!s_fpMiniDumpWriteDump(::GetCurrentProcess(), ::GetCurrentProcessId(),
                             hReportFileDmp, MiniDumpWithIndirectlyReferencedMemory,
                             &stMDEI, 0, 0))
   {
     /* ... report error ...*/
   }
   else
   {
     /* ... report ok ... */
   }

   ::CloseHandle(hReportFileDmp);
   ```

   }
     else
     {
         /* ... report error ...*/
     }
   }

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms680360(v=vs.85).aspx): "MiniDumpWriteDump should be called from a separate process if at all possible, rather than from within the target process being dumped. This is especially true when the target process is already not stable. For example, if it just crashed. ...." - Maybe try `procdump` (sysinternals) and capture a dump to compare with.

Comment: You are creating the dump at the wrong point in your GUI process. You need to install an unhandled exception filter, and pass the exception records from that handler into the `MiniDumpWriteDump` call. Apparently, you are passing `NULL`. This won't produce meaningful stack traces; you'll only get the uninteresting bottom parts, essentially just the thread startup code with the system-installed unhandled exception filter at the bottom. It's also **mandatory** to create the dump out-of-process. Otherwise you will run the risk of deadlocking the target process.

Comment: If you are running under WoW64, exceptions might get caught by the system. See [Exception Handling under WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg507671.aspx) for details.

Comment: @IInspectable Mine don't seem to, FWIW.  And you might not like me saying this, but producing the crash dump in-process almost always works for me and is better than nothing if you want to get crash dumps from users from an application that has no other option.  After all, if the application is effectively already dead then there is nothing to lose.  I even try to email them in, but that doesn't always work.

Comment: @PaulSanders: You might not like me saying this, but I have personally seen an application deadlock, trying to write a dump. Net result: A dead application with no information to diagnose the issue. If you find writing an out-of-process error dumper too tedious, configure Windows Error Reporting to do it for you.

Comment: @IInspectable Ahah! I have a solution for that too (not that I've ever seen it personally, but I don't disbelieve you).  If my app hangs at a customer site (for whatever reason) I send them a program that generates a crash dump that they can email back to me. I like this scheme because in almost every case it lets users send crash dumps direct to my inbox.  They can also tell me who they are so that I can follow up. Some users fill in their email address, some don't, but overall it works. I don't know how to do that in WER but I should probably find out. Typical me, I always roll my own.

Comment: ... and my Inbox was buzzing yesterday, don't ask.

Comment: @PaulSanders: WER does all of that, better, with less information exchanged. When a user chooses to send an error report, WER classifies that error into error buckets. Each bucket corresponds to the same bug. When you fix a bug, users get notified that there is a solution to *their* issue. This is possible since bugs can be uniquely identified, and developers can map fixes to specific versions of binaries. Setting up WER does not require any code, other than setting the respective registry keys. This is usually done from the installer.

Comment: @IInspectable Thankk you for the summary, most helpful.  I did read a little bit about it yesterday but this is still useful.  I shall investigate further, one learns a lot on this site.